# Avoiding duplicated dom queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am learning to avoid duplicated dom queries. Recommendation so far is to save the initial query into a variable and then re-use that variable as needed.

Question:

If I save the following into a variable:

```
var mylist = $("ul.mylist");
```

Will the following make another dom query?

```
mylist.find("li:first");
```

Or will it just search within that variable?

If so, is there a better way to do it? that it would avoid another query?

Comment: That second piece of code will look for the first 'li' within "mylist." It's typically best to use this if your going to be looking/chaning/etc "mylist"  a lot.

Comment: Yes and kind of yes. It will query the DOM but only the subtrees rooted at the elements in `mylist`.

Comment: It will filter the collection working on an instance of previously created jQuery object instead of creating a new one which is basically the optimisation you're looking for.

Comment: @pawel no, `.find()` will have to go back to the DOM (assuming that the original selector matched at least one `<ul>` element).

Comment: Avoiding a second query doesn't necessarily mean it'll end up being faster. This sounds like premature optimization. If you're that worried about performance, then you perhaps shouldn't be using jQuery to begin with. That'll be your biggest performance drag.

Comment: Yes, `mylist.find("li:first")` will search the DOM for the UL's first LI. It will typically be faster than `$("ul.mylist").find("li:first")` or `$("ul.mylist li:first")` because the hard part is finding the UL within the entire DOM. Searching the UL for its first LI is comparatively trivial because the search is within an already identified fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will do another "dom query". To only have 1 look-up you can save the list item node jQuery wrapper in the variable

```
var mylist = $("ul.mylist li:first");
```

Or, you can manually search within the DOM properties of the unordered list, but jQuery, I believe, won't do this for you, using the `.find()` method.

```
var mylist = $("ul.mylist");
myList[0].children[0];
// or using jquery
myList.first();
```